# Django: ForeignKey needs a default specified,what's that?

Tags: python, django

I have met this problem in django models.py
first I import a model named "User"
than I use it as a ForeignKey of one of my model "Question"

```
class Question(models.Model):
    q_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

when I try to migrate it, it tells me that I must give it a default specified.and here I have two questions:
1,I have had a ForeignKey named "Answer" which works perfectly before I add this q_user.why are they different?
2,What I should do ?I don't know how to add a default specified.
It bothers me a lot, Thank you for your replying!

Comment: Are you using South to update your database schema, perhaps?

Comment: yes,I feel really tired both before using it and after using it

Comment: South gives you the option to not specify a default too in this case; it is just trying to give you the option to handle existing Question rows.

Comment: It gives me two choices:1,quit to add it myself.2,Typing the default specified right now to add it.

Comment: I started another new project, the old one had been messed too much

Comment: South made you do this because your `ForeignKey` field is by default `NOT NULL` constrained; so existing rows must have a value. You could also have cleared your database and re-set your sout migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arises when a foreign key is added to a model, and the model is migrated using south.

Most of the time you do not want to have any null ForeignKey.
Personally, if I ever need to add such a foreign key, I assign it to a default `User` (mostly the `root` superuser).

1. Add the ForeignKey field as you have done it and do `./manage.py schemamigrate app`. South gives an option to specifiy the default on the command line. In this case, your default would be `User.objects.get(username="root")`
2. Otherwise, if you are fine with having null foreign keys, then following definition should work.

   ```
   class Question(models.Model):
       q_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
   ```

Comment: Thank you,I will have a test on it,seems great